# Some facts about probability densities

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

1(Normalization) Let $f$ be a density function and $g$ be a nonnegative function. Then show that:

$$\int|f-\frac{g}{\int g}|\leq \int |f-g|$$

2. Let $R(A):=\max(\int_{A}f_2,\int_{A^C}f_1)$, where $f_1,f_2$ are two density functions and $A$ is a set belonging to the sigma algebra. Show that the set $A=${$f_1>f_2$} minimizes $R(A)$.

My idea: for (1), I tried to use the set $Z=${$f>\frac{g}{\int g}$} and simplify the LHS to $2\int_{Z}f-\frac{g}{\int g}$.

For (2), I tried to use Scheffe's identity as $\sup_{A}|\int_{A}f_1-\int_{A}f_2|=\int_{f_1>f_2}f_1-f_2$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the value of $\int g$ for (1)? From your work one case follows in basically one step. 

There's a way to get around problem (2) without using the identity you cited, use that the maximum of 2 numbers $x,y$ is defined as $\frac{1}{2}\left( |x+y| + |x-y|\right)$.

Comment: (1) can in fact fail: take $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 1.9(1-x)$ over the domain $[0,1]$. The LHS works out to $1$, and the RHS to $<0.976.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these relations are actually false.

For the first part, take $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 1.9(1-x)$ over the domain $[0,1]$. The LHS works out to $1$, and the RHS to $<0.976.$

For the second part, take $f_1 = \frac32 \mathbf{1}\{0 \le x\le 2/3\}, f_2 = \mathbf{1}\{0 \le x \le 1\}$. Then $R(\{f_1 > f_2\}) = R([0,2/3]) = 1$. But $$R([0,1/2]) = \max\left(\frac{3}{4} ,\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac34 < 1.$$

Comment: It's weird. These statements are from the book "combinatorial methods in density estimation" pages 41 ,150.

Comment: I'm really surprised, given that it's Devroye and Lugosi. Maybe there's something particular going specifically in the context of the statements?

Comment: I know that Lugosi is very much active, and I think Devroye is also active. Maybe write them an email?

Comment: For 1., one thing to note is that in the context they're talking about on Pg. 41, one would expect that $\int g > 1.$ Maybe the inequality holds then? Second one I don't really see how to fix.

Comment: Actually, $\int g > 1$ is also not enough. Take $f = f_1$ from the answer above, and take $g = 1.5 f_2$. Then $\int | f - g/\int g| = 2/3,$ but $\int |f- g| = 0.5$.

Comment: Intuitively, for $g = f_2,$ $\int |f-g| = \int_{0}^{2/3} f - g + \int_{2/3}^1 g$. Now if you increase $g$ slightly by a constant, then the first part will decrease, the second part will increase, but then the decrease is over a larger region than the increase, so the overall integral will reduce---this continues until $g$ crosses the $1.5$ value of $f_1$. Of course, the normalised $g$ remains fixed at $f_2$.

Comment: Actually, looking at (2) again, the metric $R$ is asymmetric: Let $R_{12}(A) = \max(1-P_1(A), P_2(A))$, and $R_{21}(A)  = \max(1-P_2(A), P_1(A)).$ Then if $R_{12}(A) = P_2(A),$ meaning that $1-P_1(A) < P_2(A),$ then $R_{21}(A) = P_1(A).$ Given this, it is unclear that the minimising sets of $R_{12}$ and $R_{21}$ would be the same. The example argues that $R_{21}([0,2/3]) = 1 > R_{21}([0,1/2])$ (you were interested in $R_{12},$ but just exchange $f_1,f_2$). The natural conjecture IMO is that the minimiser of $R_{12}(A)$ is one of the sets $\{f_1 > f_2\}$ or $\{f_2 > f_1\}$, which might hold.